Cycles Render: Faint Shadows/Edges Visible on Fully Transparent Object
I have an object that I made transparent by setting the material surface alpha to 0.   However when I view the object in cycles I notice that I can still see faint weird shadows/edges from that object even though it is almost entirely invisible.   How can I get rid of these weird shadows/edges so that it is truly invisible?
For material properties > viewport display > settings, I have set "blend mode" to Alpha Clip/hashed/blend and taht did not help.  I have put "shadow mode" to alpha flip/hashed or none, no effect.
For object properties under visibility I turned off ray visibility for shadows, it only helped marginally.
Thanks


This is also happening with other objects in the scene.  When I add a few cylinders and set alpha to 0 (full transparency?) it is still visibly interacting with other transparent objects from my initial image.


Under Render Settings > Light Paths > Transparent, set from default 8 up to 20.
